# Video in full Screen not working in Android react-native-video

Tags: react-native, fullscreen, react-native-video

```
  <Video                  
          source={{ uri: "http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4" }}
          resizeMode="cover"
          repeat
          controls 
          fullscreen = {this.state.fullscreen}
          fullscreenOrientation = {"landscape"}        
          //onBuffer={this.onBuffer}                // Callback when remote video is buffering
          //onError={this.videoError}               // Callback when video cannot be loaded
          style={styles.backgroundVideo}
        />
```

I am using this above code and in the Android manifest orientation in portrait. I am click on the full screen state has been changes according to it. But it just exit in a second. As i am getting a little fluctuation and maybe the app is showing full screen and then exit from full screen. But i am not able to see it. Or you can say full screen is not working. As in the IOS it is working properly. I tried multiple from github but not able to achieve it.

Comment: I think you will need to install some other packages like this react-native-video-controls and react-native-orientation

Comment: @AregNikoghosyan i need to add some custom seekbar. so can't use this package.